# Isotropy of Space

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

Weinberg writes in his Cosmology text "Likewise,isotropy requires the mean value of any three-tensor $t_{ij}$ at $x=0$ to be proportional to $\delta_{ij}$ and hence to $g_{ij}$, which equals $a^2\delta_{ij}$ at $x = 0$" 
May someone please illuminate the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we have local isotropy, if I zoom in enough the space-time has rotational invariance. In other words, at any local point in space, the mean value of any tensor must be rotationally invariant, i.e. under rotation, we must have
$$
\langle t_{ij} \rangle \to R_i{}^k R_j{}^l\langle t_{kl} \rangle = \langle t_{ij} \rangle
$$
for all rotations $R$. In matrix notation, we must have
$$
[ \langle t \rangle, R] = 0
$$
Now, since this is true for any rotation matrix $R$, $\langle t_{ij} \rangle \propto \delta_{ij} $ (This is the statement of Schur's lemma)

Now, at $x=0$, since $g_{ij} \propto \delta_{ij}$, we have
$$
\langle t_{ij} \rangle \propto g_{ij}
$$

More generally isotropy implies that for any tensor, we must have under rotations
$$
\langle t_{i_1i_2\cdots} \rangle \to R_{i_1}{}^{j_1} R_{i_2}{}^{j_2} \cdots \langle t_{j_1 j_2 \cdots } \rangle = \langle t_{i_1 i_2 \cdots } \rangle
$$

Comment: Schur's Lemma, brilliant answer! This had been annoying me too. Thank you!